# How to use spring-jdbc in Quarkus?

Tags: java, quarkus

Could you please let me know how to use spring-jdbc in Quarkus, as I am converting my application from spring to Quarkus, for now I required to use JdbcTemplate but I don't see how to use it.

I am using below dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-spring-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

But I didn't find anything for spring-jdbc

Comment: JDBC isn't a great fit for reactive stacks, because it blocks on the IOs. Try to migrate to one of the non-blocking SQL clients Quarkus supports instead: https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-sql-clients.

Comment: Yes we are going to do it, but for now we have to start existing one with JdbcTemplate so I am looking for it.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't such thing as `JdbcTemplate` in Quarkus, nor a support for `spring-jdbc`.

So the answer is that you cannot use them, you need to convert the usage to Spring Data (or HIbernate with Panache), or inject a DataSource object and directly work with it.

Answer (score 1):

We found that past version works perfectly fine with native compilation. Hope that's good enough in your case.
Replacing logging is also required for native compilation, because of `Class.forName` usages.

```
<spring.jdbc.version>4.3.30.RELEASE</spring.jdbc.version>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.jdbc.version}</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-logging-jboss-logging</artifactId>
</dependency>
```