# "spring-jdbc" and "spring-web" compatibility with Quarkus

Tags: spring-boot, migration, quarkus, spring-jdbc

I'm new to Quarkus and I'm analysing the migration viability of a quite complex Spring Boot application.

This [post](http://code-addict.pl/quarkus-vs-spring/) raise some good questions regarding our intention on doing so with such application, but we've decided to give it a try.

For now, I'm trying to make the first step into Quarkus world, which is to get the application running on Quarkus JVM (non native option) with as little changes as possible.

At this point, I could find the following imports and features that seems not to be available on Quarkus compatibility extensions:

```
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
```

I believe the "org.springframework.orm.jpa" and "org.springframework.web.client" dependencies can be removed from application because they are associated with features nobody uses (at least I hope so), but "JdbcTemplate" is used all over the place.

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66349003/how-to-use-spring-jdbc-in-quarkus) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70600406/quarkus-alternatives-to-spring-data-jdbc) indications that "JdbcTemplate" is not available, but I would like to ask:

1- Is there any intention to make any of those features available at some point (where can I find this kind of information)?

2- Any suggestions of a good replacement for "JdbcTemplate" on this scenario?

Thanks and best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: As we can't possibly do everything, we rely a lot on the community to gauge interest for various features.

2. We generally advice users to use Hibernate in all cases, there is very little reason to drop down to something like jdbcTemplate and thus we don't provide any such alternative

Comment: I should give more information regarding the second item (JdbcTemplate alternative), but you are right, there is no reason at all to not go straight to Hibernate. I mean, although the application is quite complex, it's data base access demands are not. It's basically used to read information. Maybe that's the reason they used JdbcTemplate at first place, who knows. Anyway, thank you very much for the help and quick response.